# Ubuntu Boot Disk have wrong name

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I recently installed Ubuntu on my desktop. My PC has three hard disks: one SSD and two HDDs. The SSD has Windows and one of the HDDs is used as storage for it.

I got a new HDD for Ubuntu, and I installed onto that HDD. However, when I'm on the booting screen of the motherboard, Ubuntu seems to be on the SSD where I have Windows. Is that a poblem and how can I fix it?

[image: BIOS boot device menu]

Comment: With UEFI systems, grub only installs to drive seen as sda and then the one ESP - efi system partition is used by both Ubuntu & Windows. Boot files are in separate folders. If you want boot files in your HDD you have to partition in advance and include an ESP (FAT32 with boot flag on that drive. But grub still will not install to it, you have to manually copy files from sda to Ubuntu drive's ESP and reconfigure booting.

Answer (score 2):

No, that is not a problem. Ubuntu, like Windows, has a boot manager and that boot manager is installed by default onto the first hard drive<sup>1</sup>. The image you show just suggests that Ubuntu's boot manager (GRUB) and Windows' are both installed on the same drive. It doesn't mean that the operating systems are on the same drive, only that the BIOS sees two boot managers there.

Unless you can no longer boot Windows, in which case this is a different problem, everything should be fine.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>OK, strictly speaking, in modern systems it is installed in the [EFI partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_system_partition) which is usually in the first physical drive.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

The disk that Ubuntu installed the grub *bootloader* to is separate from where Ubuntu is actually installed. Your motherboard can boot from the SSD and find grub there, which then points to where Ubuntu was installed onto your disk. If you want to change where grub is installed, you can run:

`sudo grub-install /dev/sdX`

With 'X' being the disk where you want it instead, presumably on the same one Ubuntu is installed onto. You can use `sudo fdisk -l` if you're not sure. You then have to change your motherboard's BIOS settings to boot from that disk instead of your SSD by default.